# How do you host groovydoc on readthedocs

Tags: groovy, documentation, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

It doesn't look like there is any official support for this like there is for Java (javasphinx)

Is it possible to host groovydocs on readthedocs somehow? how hard would it be to extend Sphinx to support this? Or am I looking at this the wrong way, is there a way to convert groovy docs to Sphinx?

I want to host all of my documentation for all my languages on read the docs.